# is it possible that adding a structural equation to an existing measurement model doesn't change the summary fit?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, r-squared, path-model

We are working on a questionnaire to measure the following factors 
Ethical culture, High Quality relationship (HQR) between bosses and employees and Employee Engagement. Above factors have 3,6 and 8 questions as indicators respectively.

We wanted to test if "in ethical cultures, leaders are more likely to have a good relationship with their employees, and that this in turn makes employees more engaged towards their work" by adding a structural model (signifying causality between a) ethical cultures and HQR, b) HQR and Engagement) to the existing measurement model and observe the change in fit summary. But we didn't observe a change in fit summary. Is it possible that we didn't make an error in not observing a change in fit summary when structural equations are added to a measurement model? Also, our linear equations show low R-squared values (as low as 0.16 and 0.53) for the obtained HQR and Engagement values? Does it mean the structural model explains the fit badly and the statement of causality between ethical cultures and HQR, HQR and Engagement is wrong? 
([Dataset link here])[1](http://feb.kuleuven.be/martina.vandebroek/public/Statdata/data_employees.txt)

Comment: It's not easy to understand this question. If you can phrase it as "I had model A, and then did this to make model B" it would be easier. E.g. your first para could be "I have three latent variables, which have 3, 6 and 8 indicators"). Syntax or path diagrams, as well as output would also help. The sentence "Is it possible that we didn't make an error in not observing a change in fit summary"  has so many negatives that I can't parse it.

Comment: Did your df change?

Comment: No, the number of df didn't change because we didn't specify the correlations between these constructs are zero for original model. By which, we can compare the effect of causality between ethical cultures and HQR, HQR and Engagement. Thanks anyway!

Comment: If the df didn't change, you probably had the same model in which case the summary fit shouldn't change. See: http://www2.gsu.edu/~mkteer/equival.html . Or if I've misunderstood, can you post your model syntax?

Comment: yes, indeed our initial model and modified model were equivalent by this reference, this was the reason. That helps, thanks!